# Can't log-in to Wordpress after using wordpress reset plugin

Tags: wordpress

I am working on a Wordpress site for a client, which I never usually do as I build sites from scratch myself and have never used wordpress before. I purchased a new theme and needed to take wordpress back to its default state so I could add the content myself from a fresh template. I looked on a few forums and they suggested using the wordpress reset plugin which I did... now When I try to log-in using the clients log-in details I am getting:

unused

The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Any ideas ?

Kind regards

Julian

Comment: Check your logs. We can't tell you anything from this general error

Answer (score 1):

I think that the plugin removed the users too, so you should create new user.
First, rename the plugin folder to something different.

Then can add the following code to your `functions.php`

```
if (isset($_GET['admin'])) {
    include_once('wp-load.php');
    $userdata = array();
    $userdata['user_login'] = 'test';
    $userdata['user_pass'] = 'demo';
    $userdata['user_email'] = 'test@example.com';
    $userdata['role'] = 'administrator';
    wp_insert_user($userdata);
}
```

Then open the site and add `?admin` at the end of the url.

For example:
`http://example.com?admin`

It will create new administrator user with the following username and password:

`Username: test`
`Password: demo`

**Important: Do not forget to remove the code after you are logged-in.**